# continued fraction (trivial?) substraction

Tags: limits, continued-fractions

This is my first post!

I have been working with continued fractions, trying to perform some math on them, but I have come to a point where I'm not sure if what i'm doing is right or wrong. Any help is welcome!

So I have two functions, say $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, one with a *FINITE* general continued fraction 
$$f(n)=\frac{b_0}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{\frac{ _\ddots}{a_n-b_n}}}}}$$ 
for which I have proven that
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)=\frac{b_0}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}$$
that is, it just adds more and more $a_m+b_m$ terms on the bottom to infinity. And the second one with an *INFINITE* general continued fraction $$g(n)=\frac{c_0(n)}{a_1-\frac{c_1(n)}{a_2-\frac{c_2(n)}{a_3-\frac{c_3(n)}{ _\ddots}}}}$$ 
for which I have proven that
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty}g(n)=\frac{c_0}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}$$ 
that is, other than the top numerator the rest is the same as for $f(n)$.

I tried to perform $\lim_{n \to \infty}(f(n)-g(n))$ as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(f(n))-\lim_{n \to \infty}(g(n))=\frac{a_0}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}-\frac{c_0}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}=\frac{a_0-c_0}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}$$

is this even possible? my answer is not what I expected, so I'm guessing this substraction it's not as trivial as this... any comment?

By the way and on a more general sense, I have not very advanced programming skills or knowledge, could you provide some reference where I can learn some algorithms to calculate several decimal places, with a known error, for this kind of continued fractions? So far I have done it the direct way and with my calculator's decimal place limit (...!), how can I get better results?

Thanks very much!

---

I guess I've found the answer, thanks for your comments anyways.

For two irrational numbers, whose continued fractions must converge, we can write
$$\frac{a_0}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}-\frac{c_0}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}$$
as
$$a_0\frac{1}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}-c_0\frac{1}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}$$
that is
$$(a_0-c_0)\frac{1}{a_1-\frac{b_1}{a_2-\frac{b_2}{a_3-\frac{b_3}{ _\ddots}}}}$$
is valid, corresponding to my original question.

Nevertheless, my problem holds for in my case the continued fractions do not converge, so I'm guessing the substraction can't be performed just like that...

Comment: I changed all the $x$ to $n$, since obviously there is no $x$ anywhere in these functions

Comment: The question is interesting, however it would be better and have more of a chance to be answered here if you just provided the explicit expressions for $f(n)$ and $g(n)$

Comment: It is correct in general that if $\lim f(n)$ and $\lim g(n)$ exist, then $\lim [f(n)-g(n)]$ exists and is equal to $\lim f(n) - \lim g(n)$.